# I have a Ceiling fan wiring problem/ question

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I was putting in a new (replacement) ceiling fan in my kitchen. I have replaced many ceiling fans in this house and was prepared for the usual black/white/ blue scenario. What I saw coming out of the ceiling was a black wire out of which like the pic

[image]

I am unsure what to do with the grey wire. This fan worked well so should  I just copy the setup and attach my wires? My wife insist I put this fan in 15 years ago. But I don't remember doing it.

Comment: You mentioned 4 different colors but it's unclear from the photo which wire is what.  Also, I doubt you've provided enough information here to allow for any answer.  Wire colors are nearly meaningless until they are identified by their purpose and connection at the other end.

Comment: I've tried to de-haze & clarify the image as much as possible in Photoshop, but it's still not very clear.

Comment: In the US, grey & white are both _normally_ neutral, but can be used as hot in certain situations. How about sharing the pics of the wiring of the old fan before you disconnected everything. Also, a better pic of what you have here would be helpful, this looks like it was taken in 1973 on a Polaroid Instant...

Comment: Would guess that the "grey wire" is white and that there are two cables in parallel providing switched hot and neutral for the fan, and switched hot for the light, neutral not used in that cable (the one we are looking at.) Somewhat improper but not that unusual. Please take a better picture from slightly further back so ALL the connections can be seen. The cables being black-jackets is an indication that they are probably old, but not so old as to be cloth jackets.

Comment: Ok. I figured this out ( thank you Lord ) thanks all for your help.